# Easiest way to compare data members, from two objects of the same type

Tags: c++, c++11

I'd like to compare whether two objects (of the same type) have the same data member values. Does the STL have any way of doing this?

Comment: no. if you want to make it simple, make tuples and compare them.

Comment: maybe you need overload operator ==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the standard library will generally use `operator==` to compare two elements in a range. You can specify a custom predicate or overload `operator==`, but there is no built-in `operator==` for two class types.

```
#include <tuple>

struct Foo
{
    int a, b, c;

    bool operator==(const Foo& other)
    {
        return std::tie(a, b, c) == std::tie(other.a, other.b, other.c);
    }
};
```